# Fetching a record from an arraylist that is made up of arrays of objects

Tags: java, spring, list

I have a java arraylist that is made like this:

`{[{},{}], [{},{}], [{},{}], [{},{}]}` of around four thousand records.

I have a particular key through which I want to search in one of the objects in this list and fetch that particular array where that
record matches. The search key is a string.

Is there a solution to this without traversing through the entire list.

It is basically a list that is constructed like this:
`List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();`

I am using this to fetch the the data from two tables using a join. Individual records of each tables map to these objects.

Say table1: {a:1,b:2,c:3} and table2: {x:1,y:2,z:3}
the data returned would be

`{[{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {x:1,y:2,z:3}],[{a:2,b:3,c:4}, {x:2,y:3,z:4}]}`

How will I search for say in which array in the list is a=2.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a `Map` ?

Comment: How is it declared in java? Your object and the `ArrayList`... Please provide some code.

Comment: better you can go with hash map

Comment: How are you constructing the list? If you do not want to be a victim of the linear search, you will need to use a different data structure(hashmap?)

Comment: @jeanr actually it not much of a key/value pair that is why. They are two different objects.

Comment: @SalmanKazmi provide more detailed explanation, now it's even less clear to me

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to be a victim of the linear search, you should consider using another type of data structure than `List`.

The use case you described seems like a good match for a `Map` in general. If you want constant time key lookup, consider using `HashMap` instead.